# How to insert the date as string into a single column for all rows?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

The code below is not completing the required task. I have a table called payslip with a column called date, where I want to fill all entries in the column "date" with the current date, how to do this?

```
                String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").format(new java.util.Date());
            PreparedStatement ps0= con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO payroll_system.payslip(date) VALUES(?)");
            ps0.setString(1, date);
            ps0.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You would need an `UPDATE` (instead of an `INSERT`) and, for all of the rows, you don't need a `WHERE` clause. Oh, and you'll want a different column name because `date` is a reserved word.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ah I see the mistake, thanks, it's working now, would you like to repost your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the current date, then just use the value on the database server:

```
update payroll_system.payslip
    set date = curdate();
```